# Read a huge result set from HttpServiceClient and display them in chunks

Tags: java, timeout, httprequest

I'm writing a Java APP which reads a huge chunk of data:

```
try {
    //Build the URL
    getMethod = new GetMethod(url);
    SimpleHttpResponseParser parser = new SimpleHttpResponseParser();
    httpServiceClient.getRequest(...); //This takes about 10 minutes
    List<ApiMessage> messages = objectMapper.readValue(parser.getHttpResponse()); //Convert the JSON Response into actual Java Object
    for (ApiMessage m : messages) {
        convertedMessages.add(ApiMessageMapper.map(m)); //Add each message to a more suitable data set to be painted later
    }
    //Return the data and such ...
}
```

This request takes way to long to handle it. I don't want the user to wait over 10 minutes to see the results.

Is there a way to paint by result sets of 50 or so and keep downloading the remaining data in the background?

Comment: You should start a thread for doing it. And keep main thread unblocked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement pagination. Usually, servers allow returning a limited number of results by specifying `offset` and `limit`.

On the first call set

```
offset=0
limit=50
```

On the next call

```
offset=51
limit=50
```

and so on...

Another way is to use server push using WebSockets, but it will be a more complex implementation.